# c# System Test Automation

Tags: automation, system-testing, seetest

I am looking for a software framework which allow me to create a flexible system test solution targeted at automated testing of small networked systems. Some of the requirements are:

- .net based is preferable (the company is a big .net user and has folks that can write tests 
  in c#)
- UDP/TCP/HTTP/Websocket support
- can integrate with Test Management System such as SpiraTeam or MQC
- not looking for UNIT TEST, but for System Test involving several networked components
  which will interact with one another
- NOT a gui tester, but does allow for Squish and|or SeeTest to be integrated with Framework

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look this website, it might be useful for you

http://nunit.org/